# Using jQuery to add content to multiple elements returned by find()

Tags: jquery

How can I add content to the second and third `td`?

I just found that the following will not work.  I can find a way by creating some variable to hold the found elements, but would like to learn cleaner "more jQueryish" way if available.

```
<tr id="clone"><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>

$.each(records, function( index, row ) {
    $('#clone').clone()
    .removeAttr('id')
    .find('td')
    .eq(1).text(row.name).parent()
    .eq(2).text(row.message).parent()
    .appendTo(content)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) instead of `parent()`

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

```js
$('#clone').clone()
  .removeAttr('id')
  .find('td')
  .eq(1).text('Added 1').end()
  .eq(2).text('Added 2').end()
  .appendTo('table')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="clone">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

However I prefer having reference cloned element in a variable.

```js
var clonedElement = $('#clone').clone()
  .removeAttr('id');

//Manipulate element
var tds = clonedElement.find('td');
tds.eq(1).text('Added 1');
tds.eq(2).text('Added 2');

//Append it
clonedElement.appendTo('table');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="clone">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: May I ask why you prefer the later?  That is the way I have always done it, but you earlier script seems a little cleaner.

Comment: @user1032531, Readability and easy to understand even to a rookie dev

Comment: Yeah, I will go back to my original approach which is the same as your second example.  Regardless, thanks for the info about `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, what you are looking for could be something like the following:

```
$('#clone').clone()
.removeAttr('id')
.find('td')
 .eq(1).text(row.name).end()
 .eq(2).text(row.message).end()
 .appendTo(content)
```

`end()` will get you back to the previous selection while `parent()` will refer you up one level in the DOM model.

Comment: Again... a minute too late. That's life ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to read in the future by storing  variables for the clone and the `td`'s obtained by `find()` instead of trying to make one long chain

```
$.each(records, function( index, row ) {
    var $clone = $('#clone').clone().removeAttr('id');
    var $td = $clone.find('td');
    $td.eq(1).text(row.name);
    $td.eq(2).text(row.message);
    content.append( $clone);
});
```

Note the amount of code is not significantly different in length

Comment: No, it is not much different in length.  I just thought that the other approach might have been easier to read, and it seems that others feel the opposite.

Comment: I disagree that the chain is easier to read since each variable is quite clear what it represents and mentally walking through the chain takes more effort